# Hide when scroll down, immediately show when scroll up, pure css

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scroll, menu

I've prepared [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/phzxn2j6/3/), it uses css + js to reach the desired effect, 
a top bar that hides when scrolling down ( like a div with the default css position value ), then immediately shows up when scroll up, regardless of the current scroll value.

I've tried to get the same look&feel using pure css, with different combinations of 'sticky' position, flexbox, containers inside containers, but without any result.

It is possible to achieve the same result with pure css?
My goal is to get rid of the 'scroll' event keeping the functionality, if possible.

```js
var senseSpeed = 5;
var previousScroll = 0;
$(window).scroll(function(event){
   var scroller = $(this).scrollTop();
   if (scroller-senseSpeed > previousScroll){
      $(".item").slideUp();
   } else if (scroller+senseSpeed < previousScroll) {
      $(".item").slideDown();
   }
   previousScroll = scroller;
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  height: 5000px;
}

header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  position: sticky;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  background: DeepSkyBlue;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 999;
}

.item {
    position:fixed;
    top:50px;
    right:0;
    background-color: Orchid;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>Name</header>
<div class="item"></div>
<p>some content</p>
<p>some content</p>
<p>some content</p>
```